# SQLite Query with String-Parameter always fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sqlite

I simply want to get out the ID of an DB-entry by searching by Username

```
protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = @"Data Source=D:\DB-Files\sqlite.db; Version=3;";
    SQLiteConnection sqlCon = new SQLiteConnection(connStr);
    SQLiteCommand sqlCom = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT ID FROM TableTest WHERE UserName = @UserName", sqlCon);
    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);

    sqlCon.Open();
    int rows = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCon.Close();

    lblUserFound.Text = rows.ToString();
}
```

whatever i try, it always fails; using Visual Studio C# and SQLite Version 3; query on DB-Manager for SQLite throws out a positive result

Comment: no exception, result is always -1 (for rows affected) ---> well i mean, no rows are returned (edit)

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is the wrong method since a SELECT **is** a query..  You need to fill a datatable or use a datareader.  And you ought not use AddWithValue with SQLIte.

Comment: Also, `@UserName` vs `@Username` is likely a problem. Pretty sure named parameters are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to retrieve data. This line is wrong:

```
int rows = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`ExecuteNonQuery` only returns a value indicating if the query was run OK or not. AS you only expect one result you can use `ExecuteScalar`. Try this:

```
int rows = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCom.ExecuteScalar());
```